# Getting Error in implementing $md-sidenav from angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to implement sidenav in my application. Below is my template.

```
<div class='dashboard' ng-controller="DashBoardCtrl">
  <div layout='row'>
    <div layout='column' flex='30'>
        <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left">
            Left Nav!
        </md-sidenav>
    </div>
    <div layout='column' flex='70'>
        {{test}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller code is

```
angular.module('common').controller('DashBoardCtrl', ['$scope', 'Constants',    '$mdSidenav', function($scope, Constant, $mdSidenav) {
     $scope.$emit('HideTools', { show: true });
     $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
     $scope.test = 'to test controller binded to view';
 }]);
```

When I try to run the app I am getting error `SideNav 'left' is not available! Did you use md-component-id='left'?`

I have used `md-component-id='left'` but still facing this issue. Kindly guide me in right  way.

[image]

Comment: may be the `$mdSidenav` component is not ready. try using async call back https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdSidenav .let us know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/jVPYaK?editors=1010#0)

It looks like the `md-sidenav` is not available at the moment of the `toggle()` call. A `$timeout` allows for that to happen.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div layout='row'>
    <div layout='column' flex='30'>
      <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left">
        Left Nav!
      </md-sidenav>
    </div>
    <div layout='column' flex='70'>
      {{test}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($mdSidenav, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function () {
    $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
  });
});
```